# NVME drive timing out, system freezing

Tags: kernel, freeze, mdadm, nvme

I have a 2tb raid1 mdadm array on ubuntu server 22.04 using the HWE kernel 6.2.0-35-generic. The drives are nvme0n1 and nvme1n1

At times, sometimes under high load and sometimes not, the whole server stops responding - several realtime streams and chat programs are running, so this is very noticeable. Usually it recovers shortly, within a few minutes.

Before, and after, the kernel logs things like this (with the first lines before the freeze, and the latter after it recovers - look at the timestamps)

```
Oct 28 20:33:50 tombstone kernel: [731601.828091] nvme nvme0: I/O 1 (I/O Cmd) QID 3 timeout, aborting
Oct 28 20:33:50 tombstone kernel: [731601.828099] nvme nvme0: I/O 2 (I/O Cmd) QID 3 timeout, aborting
Oct 28 20:33:50 tombstone kernel: [731601.828106] nvme nvme0: I/O 3 (I/O Cmd) QID 3 timeout, aborting
Oct 28 20:33:50 tombstone kernel: [731601.828113] nvme nvme0: I/O 4 (I/O Cmd) QID 3 timeout, aborting
Oct 28 20:34:21 tombstone kernel: [731632.551513] nvme nvme0: I/O 0 QID 3 timeout, reset controller
Oct 28 20:34:51 tombstone kernel: [731663.266956] nvme nvme0: I/O 24 QID 0 timeout, reset controller
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731693.971274] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731693.971281] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731693.971284] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731693.971287] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731693.971290] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Oct 28 20:35:22 tombstone kernel: [731694.019253] nvme nvme0: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
```

Notably, it's always nvme0 that does this, not nvme1

I've already tried playing with the io scheduler, it doesn't seem to be that though it did help. I also tried changing the dirty memory values - currently a 300mb background setting, and something like 60 gigs hard limit, as avoiding hard pauses while data writes is paramount and lower limits still seemed to cause trouble.

From what I've found, this may point to a failing drive, but some sources suggest increasing the io timeout to an absurdly high value. I'd be willing to try that, but if the server ends up hanging forever instead of the 30s or whatever of the default timeout, that is much worse. Anyone have any input on that?

As downtime is very bad, my thought is that if this *is* a failing drive, to remove the disk from the mdadm array and run it degraded until we can schedule some downtime.

ETA: Questions

1. What causes this problem? Is it necessarily hardware failure or could I have something misconfigured?
2. Why is mdadm not dealing with this in the background, rather than causing a system freeze?
3. If this IS a failing drive, is there any downside to marking it as failed and removing it from the mdadm raid1 array, other than probably annoying messages from mdadm and obvious lack of redundancy?